# How BogoMIPS is calculated on SMP Linux Systems?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, smp

I worked on Linux kernel to implement Symmetric Multi Processing support for one ARM SoC. When Kernel was running as Uniprocessor, the BogoMIPS value was 1171. But when I turned on SMP support in Linux kernel, BogoMIPS value decreased drastically to 17. So how this value is calculated and what are the factors affecting it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bogoMIPS value is changing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463448/bogomips-value-is-changing)

Comment: [The code itself](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/init/calibrate.c#n307) is pretty easy to find. Are you perchance using a different timer source in SMP?

Comment: Yes I am using Timers of 32 kHz for both the cores of CPU.